# incorrect sidebar positioning

Tags: html, css

I'm sure this is going to end up being a super silly question/answer, however I have worked at this most of the day and am missing something quite simple.  I have tried removing div's, adding div's, and nothing.  So to keep this easy for everyone instead of me pasting a bunch of code, I have created two live pages.  The issue is that on incorrect.html, the sidebar content is pushed way down on the page, whereas correct.html is how it should be displayed. I'm not sure if my sleepy eyes are just missing an out of place div or what.
any help is greatly appreciated!

www.beerbattle.net/correct.html

www.beerbattle.net/incorrect.html

Comment: If you want some peace of mind, use a [HTML Validator](http://validator.nu/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an element that is forcing your float to clear, thus pushing your sidebar down to the bottom, even though it is still floating right. Remove

```
<div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
```

from line 252, which is right above `<div id="sidebar">`.

Comment: Sure thing. As a general rule of thumb, you're much better off not defining anything using inline CSS (anything with a style attribute). Some good tips/best practice guides can be found at [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/topics/code/htmlxhtml/), a pretty indispensable resource for any web developer.